# Counting properties of a particular class?

Tags: reflection

I'm trying to retrieve the number of properties of a certain type. For example in class Player:

```
public Player(string name, Stat endurance, Stat sprint, Stat dribble, Stat passing, Stat shooting)
{
   //Some code
}

public Stat Endurance { get; private set; }
public Stat Sprint { get; private set; }
public Stat Dribble { get; private set; }
public Stat Passing { get; set; }
public Stat Shooting { get; private set; }

public double OverallSkillLevel { get; private set; }    {

public string Name { get; private set; }    

public void CalculateAverage()
{        
    double sumOfStat = this.Endurance.Level + this.Sprint.Level + 
                       this.Dribble.Level + this.Shooting.Level + 
                       this.Passing.Level;
    //MethodOne:
    Type type =    this.GetType();
    int countOne = type .GetProperties().Count(x => x.MemberType is Stat);

    //MethodTwo
    double countTwo = this.GetType().GetFields().Count(x => x is Stat);

    //this.OverallSkillLevel = Math.Round((sumOfStat /  ), 0);
}
```

**I expect the variables "countOne " or "countTwo " to return me as a count only the properties that are Stat. But I always get 0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the wrong property of your `PropertyInfo` object; about the `MemberInfo.MemberType` property from msdn:

> When overridden in a derived class, gets a MemberTypes value indicating the type of the member - method, constructor, event, and so on.

You should check the `PropertyInfo.PropertyType` property. Also your check using the `is` keyword ist wrong in this context, when comparing `Type`-instances use `Type.IsAssignableFrom()` or `==`.

That should do the trick:

```
//MethodOne:
int countOne = this.GetType().GetProperties().Count(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(Stat));
```